# Proven/proved interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

Now it is **proven** that that medicine is harmful to people.

Now it is **proved** that that medicine is harmful to people

Here, are proved and proven interchangeable? .

Comment: There are a number of verbs in English with two past tense/participle forms. You will find some of them at: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/10-verbs-with-two-past-tense-forms-that-creeped-or-crept-into-english     and     https://www.englishforums.com/English/TwoPastParticiplesSame-Verb/mvmqx/post.htm